# laravel 5.1 css and js files are not reading

Tags: php, css, laravel-5

I have copied my assets folder to public and called my css files using

```
<link href="{{!! asset('assets/global/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css') !!}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


<link href="{{ asset('assets/global/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

but when I open my local host to view my app the css does not working and when I check the css using inspect element it shows this error

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>Object not found!</title>
<link rev="made" href="mailto:postmaster@localhost" />
<style type="text/css"><!--/*--><![CDATA[/*><!--*/ 
    body { color: #000000; background-color: #FFFFFF; }
    a:link { color: #0000CC; }
    p, address {margin-left: 3em;}
    span {font-size: smaller;}
/*]]>*/--></style>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Object not found!</h1>
<p>


    The requested URL was not found on this server.



    The link on the
    <a href="http://localhost:7777/laravel/resources/views/login.blade.php">referring
    page</a> seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of
    <a href="http://localhost:7777/laravel/resources/views/login.blade.php">that page</a>
    about the error.



</p>
<p>
If you think this is a server error, please contact
the <a href="mailto:postmaster@localhost">webmaster</a>.

</p>

<h2>Error 404</h2>
<address>
  <a href="/">localhost</a><br />
  <span>Apache/2.4.16 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1p PHP/5.6.12</span>
</address>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i use `{{URL::asset('/path/to/css')}}`

Comment: I use laravel 5.1 and this is exactly what I use in my default template:  `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{URL::asset('css/core.css')}}">` didn't have the proceeding forward slash granted but works fine for me.

Comment: I have tried every method but its not working at all :(

Comment: are you sure your files live in public/assets/global/plugins/font-awesome/css/ ? do you have your app url set correctly in config/app.php ?

Comment: I didnt checked my app.php how to resolve this? thank you so much in advance

Comment: open config/app.php and fill in the url value

Comment: view source in your browser and see what the path resolves to it should be `http://domain/path/to/css.css` you will quickly see if it is wrong and be able to adjust your `{{URL::asset('path/to/css.css')}}` to fix it

Answer (score 1):

First you put all your css and js file inside public folder.
ie, wamp->www->your project folder->public.

then in the coding section simply use the below mentioned technique.

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/jquery.datetimepicker.css"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../select/select2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../select/select2.js"></script>

<link href="../select/select2.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a slash to the beginning of your assets urls:

```
<link href="{{!!asset('/assets/global/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css') !!}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  
<link href="{{ asset('/assets/global/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```